# How to set up an existing React-Native project from a new computer for the first time?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

So I recently started working with my friend on his app project and I've had trouble building his react-native based project. It's both ios and android.

On android, I can get as far as building, but when I run the app shuts down instantly or shows a red screen with some firebase error.

On ios, I get a build error.

My question is: what do I need to install when I first pull the repo from github? I run '''yarn install''' straight away and run '''pod install''' from the ios folder but that isn't enough. Anything I should run for android more than the yarn install command I had already used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems your development environment is not set up yet. Follow [this link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) to set up your environment.

Comment: Ive set it up, uninstalled and re set up everything based on that link ~ did not solve the issue. I tried initializing my own app and that ran on both android and ios

Comment: run "adb logcat" command on terminal. It will log the error logs. please share the error logs